# Error compiling file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android programming. I'm using the studio to create a simple program, using a login activity. The build error:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: test_avd [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\NoattaAndroid\app\build\outputs\apk\app-l-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.noatta.www.noattaandroid
Installing com.noatta.www.noattaandroid
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.noatta.www.noattaandroid"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.noatta.www.noattaandroid
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

Some of the stackexchange posts talk of using L build. I tried that but did'nt work. Any suggestions anyone?

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.noatta.www.noattaandroid"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Which Android version do you have on your device?

Comment: emulator -version gives me 15. It looks like have to reduce to 10!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currenty have Android sdk version 19 (KitKat).

Your minimum SDK version in build.gradle is 20. Reduce it at least to the Android version of your emulator.

Comment: It looks like I have to reduce to 10!